# How to plot line in real time using Plotly by fetching data?

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I have created a code which fetches data from a site using api and plots the the line graph for same using Plotly.

My graph is plotted as it should but it remains static rather than being in real time.

Here is my code:

```html
import requests
import csv
import plotly.express as px

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT"

def get_latest_crypto_price():
  
  r = requests.get(url)
  response_dict = r.json()
  
  return float(response_dict['price'])


def main():
  
  last_price = -1
  eth_prices = []
  
  while True:
    
    price = get_latest_crypto_price()
  
    if price != last_price:
      eth_prices.append(price)

      fig = px.line(y=eth_prices)
      fig.write_html("file8.html")
      
      last_price = price    
        
main()
```

Kindly help in fixing my code so that my graph is plotted in real time.

Thanks in Advance